# What is meaning of 'classes' in typescript?

Tags: angular, class, typescript

While I am testing public sources implemented using Angular, I run into the following, could anyone know what this means exactly?

```
user.classes = user.classes || [];
```

I really tried getting answer searching internet, but I was not able to find it. 
'user' represents json object including user's name, email and password. I do not know what 'classes' means. Could you give some advice?

Comment: Seems like a property of a class which will remain if value exists and become an empty array if value is absent.

Comment: classes is just a property of the user object. Just as name, email, and password.

Comment: I do not think so, if I debug, user does not have classes property.. so I asked you.

Comment: To extend: both the people that commented are correct, but it looks like you're not familiar with JavaScript or TypeScript JSON: here a decent intro to object notation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx

Comment: Yes, it is one of properties of user.... sorry :)

Comment: Please accept an answer (by clicking the checkmark on the left side of the answer) on this question so others know it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know what 'classes' means. Could you give some advice?

It has no significance outside the project you are working on. You have an object called `users` that has a property called `classes`. It could easily be called anything else e.g. `users.foo`. Its just a property name specific to your project.